# How to read the option when a perl script is running?

Tags: perl

Assume that I have a perl script, which keep running in the background, say run.pl
How can I interact with this script by calling it self?
such as: perl run.pl -reload  , perl run.pl -reset

Is it possible to do it? 
If yes, which modular should I study?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot access the running instance of a program like this. You'd have to build it so that it finds out whether another instance is already running and then talking to that process by [IPC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html), e.g. signals or a socket.

Answer (score 2):

[IPC (`perldoc perlipc`)](http://p3rl.org/ipc) can be done by various methods:

1. Using sockets
2. Using signals
3. Using shared memory

I think the most simple way is handle for [signal HUP](http://p3rl.org/sigtrap) in script, and after the signal is received, read some file for additional information. Of course, you must write this file before sending the signal.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods of interprocess communications in a operating system (in case of Linux/Unix this is pipes, FIFOs, signals, shared memory and several other). Perl supports all of them.

I think, that the best solution for your task is to use signals.

So you can intercept a signal in Perl:

```
sub INT_handler {
    print("Don't Interrupt!\n");
}

$SIG{'INT'} = 'INT_handler';
```

And so you can send signals:

```
kill  9     => $pid;                    # send $pid a signal 9
kill -1     => $pgrp;                   # send whole job a signal 1
kill  USR1  => $$;                      # send myself a SIGUSR1
kill  HUP   => @pids;                   # send a SIGHUP to processes in @pids
```

More about signals in [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018452), chapter 16.8 *Sending and Receiving Signals*.

There are not so many signals available in an OS (maximum 64), and signals that you can use for your own purposes even fewer.

If you need something more powerful, use sockets or message passing systems like [ZeroMQ](http://p3rl.org/ZeroMQ).

Comment: That mean I need to use another perl script to send the signal to my running script?

Comment: Is there any method like the "squid" in Linux. It keeps running but still can handle my option when I execute "squid -k reconfigure". It seems that there are only a few signal that I can trigger. So What can I do if I have many options? Thanks.

Comment: No, you need not write another perl script; you can just use kill from the OS. `kill` is the program to send signals. When you need to pass more information then just a signal, use message passing systems, like zeromq

Answer (score 0):

Since your perl-script runs in background you can interact with it directly. But, there are few workarounds:

1. Files. You can use files as a trigger for some actions. Imagine the
   you have one copy of run.pl running in background and it constantly
   checks existing of file /tmp/file. If it does not exist the script
   simply continues checking, if it doest - the script to whatever you
   want. Some if your command "perl run.pl -reload" will create this
   file you will achieve what you want.
2. Signals. You can sent a signal to the process. How to work with
   signals in perl scripts see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Handling-the-SIGHUP-Signal-in-Daemons)